# Communicating between functional component and class component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two button components and one counter display component. The counter is supposed to display the total number of clicks by both buttons.(i.e: the counter initially displays 0, when I click button 1, counter displays 1, when I click button 2, counter displays 2).

Button 1 is written as a function component, so as the counter. I wrote a custom hook to link button 1 with the counter, and it's able to update the number when I click button 1.

I'm currently stuck with linking the class component button 2 with the function component counter.

```js
// ---------------------------------------------------
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import Count1 from './count1';
import Count2 from './count2';
import Counter from './counter';

const Index = () => {
    return (
      <Counter />
      <Count1 />
      <Count2 />
    );
}

export default Index;

// ---------------------------------------------------
// hhokstore.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const store = {
    state: {},
    setState(value) {
        this.state = value;
        this.setters.forEach(setter => setter(this.state));
    },
    setters: []
};

// Bind the setState function to the store object so 
// we won't lose context when calling it elsewhere
store.setState = store.setState.bind(store);

// This is the custom hook we'll call on components.
export function useStore() {
    const [state, set] = useState(store.state);
    if (!store.setters.includes(set)) {
        store.setters.push(set);
    }
    
    return [state, store.setState];
}

// ---------------------------------------------------
// counter.js
import React from "react";
import { store, useStore } from './hookstore';

// Setting the store initial state
store.state = 0;

const Counter = () => {
    // Using the useStore hook here as well. The same state will be shared here.
    const [timesClicked] = useStore();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                Counter: {timesClicked}
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Counter;

// ---------------------------------------------------
// count1.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { store, useStore } from './hookstore';

// Setting the store initial state
store.state = 0;

const Count1 = () => {
    // State hooks to setup initial states
    const [count, setCount] = useStore();
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count 1</button>
        </div>
    );

export default Count1;

// ---------------------------------------------------
// count2.js
import React from "react";
import {store, useStore} from './hookstore';

// Setting the store initial state
store.state = 0;

class Count2 extends React.Component {
    // Setup initial states
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        useStore(({ count }) => ({
            count: count + 1
        }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Count 2</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Count2;
```

Comment: one solution i do think is using redux. check this https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-redux-with-react-hooks-5422a7ceae6e

Comment: class components cant use hooks, if you would like to connect both, set the handle click on the parent and pass it down to counters componets as a callback